# Azure Data Factory, the factory name as a parameter

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am looking at updating my Azure Data Factory pipeline, to make it easier to copy across the database instances. Dev, Test, Production.

I have three different Data Factories, Factory_D_ADF, Factory_T_ADF, and Factory_P_ADF. The instance is depicted by the 'D', 'T' and 'P'. For each of these they will use different connections which I can set as parameters.

I can then template the pipeline and depending on which instance it is in, it will then use the correct values for these parameters.

My question is, is there a way of pulling this information, the Data Factory name, into the pipeline so that I can use this to determine which values to use for the parameters?

I've been reading through other methods, however I am working with what I have been supplied with and feel this would be the easiest way to control the datasets used for the pipelines.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@pipeline().DataFactory` to get the ADF's name. See the docs page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables).

Comment: Excellent, I've been searching for this page.